# PHP not uploading file

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a file using php and store the files information in a database. The database part is working correctly, however I am trying to move the files to a directory called videos/, however the files are not moving to this directory. Here is my php code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('manchesterunited');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($temp,"videos/".$name);
    $url = "localhost/manchesterunited/videos/$name";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO video VALUES ('','$name','$url')");
}
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by the files are not moving?  What does the php error_log say ?  what does the system log say ?

Comment: It doesnt say anything in the error logs. The files are not moving from one directory to another after upload.

Comment: Do you have error checking turned on? If so, is PHP outputting anything to the browser? Have you [checked the return value of move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to make sure the move was successful?

Comment: Use the full path on your calls and it should work. Also check if tmp file exists with file_exists() before moving.

Comment: The way you have your code written, it is trying to move the files to the directory `videos` as a sub-directory of tmp. Does tmp/videos exist? Try changing the permissions of `tmp/videos` to 777 temporarily - to see if it is a permissions issue.  That is about the only idea I have

Comment: I dont want the directory to be tmp/videos i want the directory to just be videos/ how can i ammend the code to that?

Comment: Try before `videos`  `/videos/`:

`move_uploaded_file($temp,"/videos/".$name);`

Comment: I temporarily created a directory in xampp's tmp folder named videos and set the permissions accordingly, this still did not even move the video to there - even with the existing code.

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev nope that doesnt work sorry :)

Comment: Please past this function **`error_reporting(E_ALL);`** in upload page, to see **ERROR**

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev there are no errors apart from not using mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code with replacing "/full/path/to/" with the actual directory. Usually this is something like "/home/username/public_html/"

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $dir = '/full/path/to/manchesterunited/videos/';
    $file = $dir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp,$file);
    $url = "localhost/manchesterunited/videos/$name";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO video VALUES ('','$name','$url')");
}
?>
```